# How do I save a users location and display it on a map using a pin (or some other marker)?

Tags: swift, gps, xcode6, mapkit, core-location

What I want to do is have a button that the user can click that would save their current location. Then, on a map, a pin would appear where the save location is. How would I go about doing this? I've searched for some sample code but I can't find any that work or are in Swift.

I have it so the user can also see where they are at at all times. Bellow is what I currently have for code.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()


@IBOutlet var Map: MKMapView!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {

    println("Updating Location \(newLocation.coordinate.latitude) , \(newLocation.coordinate.longitude) ")





    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.0009, 0.0009)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: newLocation.coordinate, span: span)
    Map.setRegion(region, animated: false)
}
}
```

What would I add to this code to accomplish my goal that I described in my first paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

- Create your button action to `findUserLocationAndDropPin()`:
- Capture the `userLocationCoordinates` using
  `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake()`;
- Create your `pinForUserLocation` using  `MKPointAnnotation()`;
- Assign your `pinForUserLocation.coordinate` to be equal to
  `userLocationCoordinates`;
- Get your `mapView` and `addAnnotation`;
- Finally ask `mapView` to `showAnnotations`.

This code is what I mean and should do that, at least until iOS 8.4 :

```
@IBAction func findUserLocationAndDropPin(sender: UIButton) {
        var userLocationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude)
        var pinForUserLocation = MKPointAnnotation()
        pinForUserLocation.coordinate = userLocationCoordinates
        mapView.addAnnotation(pinForUserLocation)
        mapView.showAnnotations([pinForUserLocation], animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: [Picture](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/10yFq6U54FicQhdmtRGrPjzONvd0sDo5jeG6g8uPVlew/edit?usp=sharing)     I am getting these errors that are shown in the picture. Can you help me please?

Comment: I checked your link. To correct you must name `mapView` with the name of your MKMapView variable, remember that variables' name must start with a lower case letter.

Comment: [Picture](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/10yFq6U54FicQhdmtRGrPjzONvd0sDo5jeG6g8uPVlew/edit?usp=sharing)    Thank you for getting back to me so fast. I tried that and I got these errors.

Comment: Ok, in your code delete your IBOutlet named Map, go to your Storyboard click on your MAP object using the mouse left button, find the Map outlet and delete that also. Let start again, now recreate your MAP IBOutlet naming it mapView.

Comment: YOU HAVE NO CLUE HOW HAPPY YOU JUST MADE ME!!!! Now I have two more questions. what code do I need to delete the pin when a new one is added?

Comment: Think you should go to the font...https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html, you will probably learn better.

Comment: I've skimmed through and I can't find where it says how... and its all for objective c. I am using Swift.

Comment: You should make `pinForUserLocation` a global variable if you want to access from another func, then you could do something like: `mapView.removeAnnotation(pinForUserLocation)`, for more check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKMapView

Answer (score 1):

Good question!

Try adding an array that stores `newLocation.coordinate` when an `IBAction` takes place. Then, you can set a pin by using this sample code as an example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set map view delegate with controller
    self.mapView.delegate = self

    let newYorkLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.730872, -74.003066)
    // Drop a pin
    let dropPin = MKPointAnnotation()
    dropPin.coordinate = newYorkLocation
    dropPin.title = "New York City"
    mapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)
}
```

But then just set `dropPin.coordinate` to be the value stored in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so firstly you want to get permission from the user:

- Add the CoreLocation framework
- Update info.plist by adding NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
- Your code in viewDidLoad is correct
- You can use the simpler method:

  ```
  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) { }
  ```
- Inside that, set:

  `var userLocation : CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation`
- Now create a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` by using `userLocation.latitude` and `.longitude`
- create an annotation with `MKPointAnnotation()`, and set `annotation.coordinate` to be the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` above.
- set the `.title` if required
- `map.addAnnotation(annotation)`

This will in effect add a pin every time the user's location is updated - so you might want to think about removing the previous pins. Also, it's not very effective if y you're getting updates every half second or so, so consider simply setting the mapView to show the *region* every time it is updated, rather than a pin.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How would I remove the previous pin when a new one is added?

Comment: You could declare the annotation at the top (so within the class) - and use map.removeAnnotation(annotation) before the code to create an annotation... so you'd only ever have one pin on the map at a time.